# Explode function on nested JSON

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am struggling to perform a consecutive "explode" function on the following json struct

```
 |-- DEF: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- PIT: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- BIT: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- S_BIT: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- T_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- edge: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- insDef: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- insName: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to extract all the values in the PIT array element into a tuple in order to set them into the PIT object (Please correct me if there is a better approach). The following command returns a WrappedArray. But I'd like an array in order to perform map function on it (to set the variables as class members).

```
FROM levelTable SELECT cat LATERAL VIEW explode(DEF.UPIT) table1 AS cat
```

UPDATE1:
The following command returns all the "name" values from the child element PIT.

```
FROM levelTable SELECT cat LATERAL VIEW explode(DEF.UPIT[0].name) table1 AS cat
```

But I am still looking to convert them as a Array of Tuple(PIT.name, DEF.insName, DEF.insDef)